# What does it mean by a "6 channel DMA"?

Tags: microcontroller

While I was going through the architecture of TMS320F2806x (Piccolo) MCUs, I have found that one of the features that it has is, a 6 channel DMA. Can you please elaborate what does it mean by *channels* of DMA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DMA allows for transfer of data from one location to another without using the CPU.  It is done by the 'DMA Controller'.  A multi-channel DMA controller can facilitate more than one DMA transfer at a time.  The Piccolo can facilitate 6 DMA transfers concurrently.